# rails nested forms link_to_add error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I am generating a nested form, in which i want to add the 'link_to_add' option of nested_forms:

```
<%= nested_form_for(@practice) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :uebung_maps do |map| %>
    <%= map.hidden_field :role_id, :id => "role_id_#{@runs}"  %>
    <%= map.hidden_field :vehicle_id, :id => "vehicle_id_#{@runs}"  %>
  <% end %>
  <%= nested.link_to_add '+', :uebung_maps %>
<% end %>
```

Now if i refresh the page, following error occures:

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

i am using the nested_forms gem with version 0.3.1 to build the form. what is wrong here?
And what aditional information should i provide here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like either `@practice` or `@runs` is not set - are you sure you have set both in your controller?

Comment: In my Controller i do => 8.times Practice.uebung_maps.build
How do I have to add it to the link_to_add button?